# asp.net Dropdown list databinding in runtime

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

```
 con = new SqlConnection(s);
        con.Open();
        if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select [Item] from Veg_Items", con);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "[Item]");
            DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
        else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select [Item] from NonVeg_Items", con);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "[Item]");
            DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            DropDownList1.DataBind();

        }
            con.Close();
    }
```

I have items in my table and I need my items to be displayed in `Dropdownlist` once I select any value in `RadioButtonList`.
I also visualized the items in `ds.Tables[0]` line but I can't bind them to `Dropdownlist`.

Comment: Your query download data or not? The problem is with only bind data?

Comment: Can you try adding DataTextField and DataValueField of DropDownList to some column in DataTable i.e. DropDownList1.DataTextField = "<Column Name"

Comment: It just fetches the items in that table.@mwisnicki

Comment: its not working @RohitGarg

Comment: can you post the snapshot of the ds.Tables[0] so that we can see the column and data inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  con.Open();
        if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select [Item] from [Veg_Items]", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<Object> lt = new List<Object>();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    lt.Add(dr["Item"].ToString());
                }
            }
            DropDownList1.DataSource = lt;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
        else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select [Item] from [NonVeg_Items]", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<Object> lt = new List<Object>();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    lt.Add(dr["Item"].ToString());
                }
            }
            DropDownList1.DataSource = lt;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
  }
  con.Close();
```